# Is it acceptable to speak of "acute" and "chronic" exercise?

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-usage

Today, I was attending a scientific conference, and the presenter (likely an ESL speaker) used the phrases "acute exercise" and "chronic exercise" to refer to short term and long term exercise in experimental mice.

Is this usage valid, or is it merely a malapropism?

Comment: I am not sure what the intent of the author was, and it's conceivable that those words are used metaphorically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they seems to be used at medical scenarios:

"Blood pressure responses to acute and chronic exercise are related in prehypertension"

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22899388